# How to access an extra field in an m2m intermediary table from my admin model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models `Tender` and `Status` joined in a M2M relationship by a bridge table `TenderStatus`. The bridge table has an extra date field in it. I'm using an inline for the admin form. But I want to be able to display the date from the intermediary table in the admin view. I can access the *name* of the Status, so I can easily show a comma-separated list of statuses for example, but I cannot figure out how to access the date field. I've tried using a callable in the admin class to no avail (I think I just don't know how to access the date field from the callable). I also created a custom **str** function for TenderStatus, but it doesn't seem to pay attention to that. Here's the code I have so far:

models.py

```py
class Tender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tender_status = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Status',
        through='TenderStatus',
        related_name='tender_status'
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tender'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TenderStatus(models.Model):
    tender = models.ForeignKey('Tender', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=False)
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False,)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date) + ': ' + str(self.status)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tender_status'

class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'status'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.status)
```

admin.py

```py
class TenderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):

    list_display = ['name', 'status_list']

    def status_list(self, obj):
        # I BELIEVE THIS IS THE ELEMENT I NEED HELP WITH, HOW TO CALL THE DATE HERE
        # THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK
        return [str(x.date) + ': ' + x.status for x in obj.tender_status.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = 'Tender'
```

Note: My app does not use custom views, it *only* uses the admin models. I do not have the option to add custom views, as the organization will not permit it.

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking for a way to list out the statuses + dates in a string formatted way in the `list_display`, using only what is available in django-admin.

Comment: This is just for the `list_display`?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, exactly. Sorry, I should have specified. I'll add something above.